# bootstrap-select not updating dynamically in angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular6

I have a select ([bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/)) in my web page which consist of some data that will update according to some filter. The data is bonded to the select via API.

```
     <select  appBootstrapSelect  data-live-search="true" [(ngModel)]="mCompany" >
          <option value=''>All</option>
          <option *ngFor="let motherCompany of motherCompanies " [ngValue]="motherCompany.id">                       
           {{motherCompany.name}}
         </option>
     </select>
```

Some initial data is filled in the select during `ngOnInit` and this works fine. But when I try to update the `options` of `select` via code by changing the model, it does not seem to reflect. One thing I noticed is that if I removed the attribute `appBootstrapSelect` the `select` will be having a default style and binding from code works which is the behavior I want.

`appBootstrapSelect` is a `Directive` and the code for it is as below

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

declare var jQuery: any;

/**
 * Directive to wrap bootstrap-select
 */
@Directive({
  selector: '[appBootstrapSelect]'
})
export class BootstrapSelectDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private el;

  constructor(private elref: ElementRef) {
    this.el = elref.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   // wrapping in setTimeout to delay init until after attribute binding
    setTimeout(() => {
      jQuery(this.el).selectpicker({
        iconBase: 'fa',
        tickIcon: 'fa-check'
      });
    },2000);

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    jQuery(this.el).selectpicker('destroy');
  }

  refresh() {
    jQuery(this.el).selectpicker('refresh');
  }

  /**
   * Manually dispatch a change event to let Angular know of a programmatic change to the select
   */
  triggerChangeEvent() {
    this.el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { 'bubbles': true }));
  }

  /**
   * Select an option in this select by id
   * @param id
   */
  selectOptionById(id) {
    jQuery(this.el).find('#'.concat(id)).prop('selected', true);
    this.triggerChangeEvent();
  }
}
```

I found a  [jQuery code](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh) I think that need to be called in order for the list to update but not sure how to do the same in angular. I do have a model reference for `appBootstrapSelect`

```
 @ViewChildren('appBootstrapSelect') motherCompanyDropdown: ElementRef;
```

Why might this be happening ? How can I solve this ?

PS: I have also tried `ChangeDetectionStrategy` but does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hello,

since you already have the `refresh` method in your directive, all you need to do is call it when updating the options data.
To call it from the component you need to use `ViewChild` like below:

Your component.ts

```js
@ViewChild(BootstrapSelectDirective) motherCompanyDropdown: BootstrapSelectDirective;
//...
update() {
  // new data
  this.motherCompanies = [...];
  // call refresh
  this.motherCompanyDropdown.refresh();
}
```

But since you use setTimeout it may not work without adding setTimeout too in your `refresh` method:

Your directive.ts

```js
refresh() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    jQuery(this.el).selectpicker('refresh');
  })
}
```